# Meu código em C compila mas não é executado

Tags: c, compilação

O código é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int qtdDeElementos;
    int vetor[qtdDeElementos];

    printf("Informe a quantidade de elementos do vetor: ");
    scanf("%i", &qtdDeElementos);
    
    return 0;
}
```

o vetor que declarei ainda não tem nenhum papel no meu programa porque ele ainda não está completo. Eu escrevi esse pequeno trecho e decidi compilar e executar para testar se estava tudo certo até ali. Acontece que só compila, mas não executa. Já testei outros códigos e todos eles são compilados e executados como esperado.

Obs importante: o código acima funciona normal se eu remover a declaração do vetor.

Obs2: Estou utilizando extensões para executar o código pelo VSCode, mas já tentei pelo cmd e o problema persiste.

Comment: Você está criando o seu vetor, e reservando uma quantidade de memória para ele antes de ler a `qtdDeElementos`. Assim sendo, decerto ele vai ser criado do tamanho errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você declarou o vetor sem um valor predefinido. Primeiro você deve ler o valor da variável "qtdDeElementos" e logo em seguida declarar o vetor.

Segue o exemplo (coloquei o laço 'for' para preencher e imprimir os espaços do vetor):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    const int qtdDeElementos;

    printf("Informe a quantidade de elementos do vetor: ");
    scanf("%i", &qtdDeElementos);

    int vetor[qtdDeElementos];

    for(int i = 0; i<qtdDeElementos; i++)
    {
        vetor[i] = i;
        printf("vetor[%i] = %i\n", i, vetor[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```